# Extract particular values from mongoldb array using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a mongoDB database with the following structure. Is it possible to extract values based on Exam, Start and End.

```
[
{
"UserID": "User1",
"USER": {
    "Exam": [
        "Math",
        "Python",
        "Physics",
        "Chem",
        "Physics"
    ],
    "Start": [
        6,
        4,
        2,
        9,
        11
    ],
    "End": [
        249,
        135,
        135,
        133,
        115
    ]
  }
},
{
"UserID": "User2",
"USER": {
    "Exam": [
        "Physics",
        "Chem",
        "Maths",
        "English",
        "Python"
    ],
    "Start": [
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    "End": [
        2497,
        1355,
        1350,
        1338,
        1151
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

For example if query is for UserID = "User1", Exam = ["Physics", "Python"], Start = [1, 8], End = [159, 90]. The output should be

```
{
   "UserID": "User1"
   "Exam": [
      "Physics"
   ],
   "Start": [
     2
   ],
   "End": [
     135
   ]
}
```

Only those exams are returned for which the **start** provided in the **query** is **less than or equal** to the **start** in the **database** and the **end** is **greater than or equal** to the **end** in the **database**.

Comment: Are you trying to pair the first element of each array for the purpose of the query?  If so, why not store them together in an object?

Comment: It's a standard and I have to store it like that.

Comment: "is it possible...?" - the answer is clearly yes.  I'll be curious to see if any answers can tame the tedious nature of the document and query formats.  Even after a `$match`, `$zip`, and `$unwind`, it doesn't look like fun.